# Git Structure when dealing with clients

Tags: git, github, version-control

Please bear with me. I'm not a git expert so I may be wrong with everything I'm even saying here.

Ok. So I saw a few questions that are similar to this one. However, I feel like mine is different enough to ask here.

We have several microapps that we have created in Github. I feel I took out all of the common parts between the microapps and separated them into a sort of library for all of the microapps to use.

Clients will purchase our microapps but sometimes want them customized in a way that's not as common. However, no matter what there are a majority of files that don't change in each microapp.

I created a repository for each microapp and for the library. I have questions on how to structure the clients' repository.

My current structure is the following:

```
MicroApp1
|-- File 1
|-- File 2
|-- File 3

MicroApp2
|-- File 1
|-- File 2
|-- File 3

MicroAppLibrary
|-- File 1
|-- File 2
|-- File 3
```

My first question would be how should I include the library in the main microapp repositories? From my understanding, I should use submodules. I want to be able to update the library repository and merge it to all of the microapp repositories.

My second and deeper question is how I should structure the clients' repositories? The way I'm thinking of doing it is by having one repository for each client. In each repository, I would have directories basically containing the repositories. Like the following (if i don't do the submodule and instead just clone the library every time):

```
Client 1
|-- MicroApp1
    |-- File 1
    |-- File 2
    |-- File 3
|-- MicroApp2
    |-- File 1
    |-- File 2
    |-- File 3
|-- MicroAppLibrary
    |-- File 1
    |-- File 2
    |-- File 3
```

My problem with that is how to update and merge the code to all of my clients' repositories? For example, If I make a change in the main repository of a microapp, how would I push that change to all of my clients' repositories? It doesn't seem like I can merge a repository to a directory. Would I instead use branches? There's quite a few microapps, and I would want a dev and prod branch on each of them as well.

I have many more questions but feel like it'll be too much for one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Forget about submodules, use subtree
2. If GitHub, then each client's MicroApp repo is created as fork of base MicroApp, and all customer-specific customization performed in it, while you can always pull common changes from base

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer. Would I be able to have multiple forks in one repo? (One fork per microapp) Or would I need to create one repo per client per microapp? I wanted to have all of my clients' microaapp in one place.

Comment: @ElCree - each fork is repo, with subtree you can have any number of repos in one "superrepo", thus - yes, you can combine all client's apps-repos into one

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How would I go about maintaining all of those branches? Would it be a set of branches for each forked repo? does GitHub categorize them at all? Or would I have to categorize it using a naming convention?

Answer (score 1):

There's a special GitHub App for that, called [Git X-Modules](https://github.com/marketplace/git-x-modules). Unlike submodules, this tool allows you to add only certain folders from a repository as a module, and updates automatically in the background. So you can create a separate repository for each of your client, add the needed components to it, and set up a one-way synchronization (so that updates from the main project repo are pulled to the clients' repos, but not vise versa).

Comment: I was thinking of only using submodules for the common library that the microapps use. Are you saying to use submodules for the actual microapps? How would I go about maintaining the branches?

Comment: @ElCree My suggestion was to have something like this:

Client 1
|-- MicroApp1
    |-- File 1 - a shared library for all apps, synchronized with its own repository
    |-- File 2 - a core file in this microapp, synchronized with the app repository you maintain
    |-- File 3 - a client-specific (customized) file in the microapp

In this case you create a repository for each client, then add shared libraries and core files as X-modules. With Git X-Modules you can add only a certain directory as a module, not the whole repository.

What is the question about branches?

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but with all of the microapps. My question with branches would be how to deal with all of that in one repo